# Problems splitting scraped data with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

I am trying to scrape the data on some pages with BeauitfulSoup but I cannot seem to get the data that I want. I am having trouble splitting the data. I'll post my code below but what I am trying to do is grab each address and split it. For instance, if you try the code below, I can get the data that I want but I can't seem to figure out how to split it on the 
 tag. My output I am attempting is, `address = ['2 Warriston's Close','High Street, Edinburgh EH1 1PG','United Kingdom']`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

url = 'https://www.hauntedplaces.org/item/mary-kings-close/'

page = requests.get(url)

soup = bs(page.text, 'lxml')

region = soup.select('dd.data')[0]
# Need something here to split the region variable so I can separate for csv file. 
# Trying to use soup.select('dd.data')[0].split() but no avail. 
print(region)
```

Comment: What does `print(region)` output?

Comment: `<dd class="data">2 Warriston's Close<br/>
High Street, Edinburgh EH1 1PG<br/>
United Kingdom<br/>
<br/><br/>
<b><a class="general-button" href="/directions.php?lat=55.94993923670036&amp;long=-3.1907854865081617" target="_new">Get Directions »</a></b>
</dd>`

Answer (score 0):

So, instead of the HTML, you want to get the text inside of the tags. BeautifulSoup has a `text` attribute. So, in this case to get what you want you can just add the line:

`print(region.text.split('\n')[:3])`